# Simple Contact form returning "Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." on submission

Tags: ee5, email-contact-form

I have set up a simple contact form on a new installation of Expression Engine 5.2. Email module is installed. This submits ok on localhost but on the server I am getting hit with the titular error.

[image]

My code:

```
                    {exp:email:contact_form recipients=my@email.com" charset="utf-8" form_class="iwd-standard-form"}

                    <fieldset class="iwd-fieldset-contained">
                        <legend>Your contact details</legend>
                        <div class="iwd-form-row">
                            <div class="iwd-form-labels">
                                <label for="name">*Name:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="iwd-form-controls">
                                <input name="name" placeholder="Your name" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="iwd-form-row">
                            <div class="iwd-form-labels">
                                <label for="from">*Email:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="iwd-form-controls">
                                <input name="from" placeholder="Your email" type="text" value="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="iwd-fieldset-contained">
                        <legend>Leave us a message</legend>
                        <div class="iwd-form-row">
                            <div class="iwd-form-labels">
                                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="iwd-form-controls">
                                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Enter message" style="height:200px"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset class="iwd-fieldset-uncontained">

                        <div class="iwd-form-row center">
                            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{csrf_token}">
                            <button id="form-submit" type="submit" class="iwd-button submit-form">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                {/exp:email:contact_form}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I just solved this. I've got 2 urls, one redirects to the other.

Base path was set wrong in URL and path settings (set to the redirecting url)

Works fine once I updated the settings.